# Square-Connect 422 error when trying to add item with category_id

Tags: square-connect

I receive a 422 response when I include a "category_id" in the item body (when I don't include the category_id it works fine).

Here is the json object that fails

```
{
 "name":"9001 Donald Duck",
 "category_id":"284958c8-c837-41b3-8984-6faf2589bcf5",
  "abbreviation":"9001",
  "visibility":"PRIVATE",
  "variations":[
    {"name":"credit card payment",
     "pricing_type":"FIXED_PRICING",
     "price_money":{"currency_code":"USD","amount":"100"}
     }]
 }
```

I added the item without the category_id successfully,  and then linked it to the category using the dashboard,  and then did an item listing to make sure I was using the correct category.

Here is the response of the listing (with the same category):

```
{
 "visibility":"PRIVATE",
 "available_online":false,
 "available_for_pickup":false,
 "id":"4a4c2d1d-ddb7-4b45-b432-f511c5a92117",
 "name":"9001 Donald Duck",
 "taxable":false,"abbreviation":"9001",
 "category_id":"284958c8-c837-41b3-8984-6faf2589bcf5",
 "category":{
      "id":"284958c8-c837-41b3-8984-6faf2589bcf5",
      "name":"Annual Auction & Party Bidders (7fa314q7)"},
 "variations":[
      {"pricing_type":"FIXED_PRICING","track_inventory":false,
       "id":"010fecb9-bd21-406b-bf13-ec42eff07e64",
       "name":"credit card payment",
        "price_money":{"currency_code":"USD","amount":100},
       "ordinal":0,
       "item_id":"4a4c2d1d-ddb7-4b45-b432-f511c5a92117"
      }]
  },
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is in fact a bug—thank you for bringing it to our attention. I will update this question when it is resolved.

Comment: This issue should now be resolved. Can you try again? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately,  I am receiving a java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server when I test.  I don't think this relates specifically to your fix,  I think your server is not so stable,  and code that was working yesterday is broken today